# I want to Show image Like pagination in my home page

Tags: php

I want to Show image in home page like Pagination Model in php..

For example,

I have 50 images in my database mean i am showing images in Slider So first few minutes show 1 to 10 images and then next step it show 10 to 20 and then 20 to 30 like that dont show that same image again and again next step.

Comment: Are you want to show via javascript? or you want to load 10 image for each refresh of the page for current session?